# Funcion que reciba un string y lo retorne como objeto

Tags: javascript, string

/*
Escribe una función llamada frecuencias que reciba un string y retorne un objeto con el número de veces que aparece cada carácter (exceptuando el espacio en blanco):
*/

```
function frecuencias(frase){
    for(i=0; i<length.frase; i++){
       frase.indexOf([i]);
    }
    return frase[i]
}
    
    // código de prueba
    console.log(frecuencias("hola mundo")) // "
    //Resultado esperado { h: 1, o: 2, l: 1, a: 1, m: 1, u: 1, n: 1, d: 1 }
    
    console.log(frecuencias("anita lava la tina"))
    //Resultado esperado { a: 6, n: 2, i: 2, t: 2, l: 2, v: 1 }
```

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega que llevas hecho al momento, lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto puede servir:

```
function frecuencias(frase) {
    let result = {};
    for(let c of frase.split('')) {
        if (c == ' ')
            continue;

        if (!result[c])
            result[c] = 1;
        else
            result[c]++;

    }

return result;
}

console.log(frecuencias("hola mundo"));
console.log(frecuencias("anita lava la tina"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/auc529mq/

Comment: Gracias @ByronNizo, ese es el algoritmo que cumple para el resultado esperado, igualmente me despejaste muchas dudas.